# Switch second gamepad (from the same vendor) to player2

Tags: drivers, gamepad

I bought two similar [gamepads](https://www.speedlink.com/ru/Gaming/TORID-GAMEPAD-WIRELESS-FOR-PC-PS3-BLACK.html) and I want to play in games for 2 players on [ePSXe](https://www.epsxe.com/), however ePSXe recognizes both gamepads as player1.
After researching couple of days, I still can not find a solution to this.
This command `xboxdrv --list-controller` shows:

```
 id | wid | idVendor | idProduct | Name
----+-----+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------
  0 |   0 |   0x045e |    0x028e | Microsoft X-Box 360 pad
  1 |   0 |   0x045e |    0x028e | Microsoft X-Box 360 pad
```

When I try to assign buttons in ePSXe I see the same keycode.

- E.g. Config -> Game Pads -> Port 1 -> Pad 1 -> `up` button shows `386`
- Config -> Game Pads -> Port 2 -> Pad 1 -> `up` button shows `386` also.

Connecting these gamepads to Windows 10 and running ePSXe works fine.

- Config -> Game Pads -> Port 1 -> Pad 1 -> `up` button shows `J1_UP`
- Config -> Game Pads -> Port 2 -> Pad 1 -> `up` button shows `J2_UP`

On the other hand `antimicro` program recognizes two gamepads correctly, when I hit button on 1 gamepad -> 1st tab is blinking and shows what exactly button is it. The same with gamepad 2.

The problem might connected with Ubuntu drivers, cause ePSXe works well on Windows10 with the same gamepads. Any ideas how to solve this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I found similar issue at https://askubuntu.com/questions/743662/how-to-reorder-gamepads

Comment: For now I solved this by switching to another amulator. https://github.com/JaCzekanski/Avocado helped

Comment: Turns out that `ePSXe` is outdated and not supported anymore. I found the best one emulator https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation - this works perfectly with all favorite PS1 games and with my controllers!